# combine multiple functions to one function

Tags: php, function

I am trying to combine 3-4 functions inside one function and call this inside another function. 
for example

```
public function user($user) 
{ if($user==''){ $this->logerror('not valid'); //this stores error in the db
 return false; } 
}
```

I have one more for email like this

```
public function email($email) 
    { if($email==''){ $this->logerror('not valid'); //this stores error in the db
     return false; } 
    }
```

So now I want to write a function called "validate" and then put the above two functions. then I will call this "validate" in other places when I want to validate user and email. I am not understanding how the arguments will be for the "validate" function when I want to use it. Please let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but if you want to have  a function that wants to validate both of these, two calls should do the trick.

Comment: yes, it is not clear, do you mean a: `function one4all($what, $toDo){...}`  if this is the case, just use `switch($toDo)`

Comment: You may want to rename your functions and change what you return in them.  I don't think most people would expect a function named `user` to return `false` or `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want ?

```
public function validate($user, $email) 
{ if($user=='' and $email != ''){ $this->logerror('not valid'); //this stores error in the db
 return false; } 
}
```

Comment: I think something like this will be helpful. will work in this direction. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're trying to do ?

```
<?php
public function checkData($data) 
{
  if($data == '') {
    $this->logerror('not valid'); //this stores error in the db
    return false; 
  } 
}

checkData($email);
checkData($user);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function user($user){
    if($user==''){ 
        $this->logerror('name not valid'); //this stores error in the db
        return false; 
    }else{
        return true;
}

public function email($email){ 
    if($email==''){ 
        $this->logerror('email not valid'); //this stores error in the db
        return false; 
    }else{
        return true;
    } 
}

public function validate($name, $email){
    if(name($name) && email($email){
        // Then the form is valid
    }else{
        // the form  is not valid
    }
}
```

The function validate will validate both the name and the email parameter passed